# cd command does not changed to variable value change directories

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo, cd

Here the value is coming correct in the variable lastoccur and also it is echoed

but the cd command to move to that directory does is seemingly not working. Why is this happening?

```
@echo off
mode con: cols=157 lines=2500
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=2" %%G in ('p4 client -o 2850NewDev ^| findstr /c:"Root:"') do (
    set lastoccur=%%G
)

cd /d !lastoccur!
echo !lastoccur!
PAUSE
```

**UPDATE 1**

I changed the code to this:

```
@echo off
mode con: cols=157 lines=2500
set lastoccur=""

for /f "tokens=2" %%G in ('p4 client -o 2850NewDev ^| findstr /c:"Root:"') do (
    set lastoccur=%%G
)

cd %lastoccur%
echo %lastoccur%
PAUSE
```

Now also cd does not change the directory. I am not seeing any path on the window, just the echoed value.

Comment: That depends entirely on what the output of `p4 client -o 2850NewDev` looks like.

Comment: @SomethingDark The value finally setting in lastoccur variable is: c:\fold1\fold2

Comment: What I want is to set the value in lastoccur variable and change the directory to the stored value, outside the loop.

Comment: I know what you want; you explained your problem just fine. If the output if `p4 client -o 2850NewDev` is `C:\fold1\fold2` and you're searching that output for `Root:`, you aren't going to find it so `%lastoccur%` isn't getting set and `cd` won't take you anywhere.

Comment: Corrected my statement.

Comment: Infact cd command is not working at all, even to static paths.

Comment: Does `pushd` work?

Comment: I tried that too but of no help.

Comment: I think I got the issue. It is because of @echo off. When I removed it I was able to see the changed directory. But it also shows all my commands executing. How to prevent that?

Comment: It's not because of `@echo off` (all that does is prevent commands from being displayed before they are executed), it's because of `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. See my answer for details.

Comment: What does the `cd` command do? It should either change the dir or throw an error message. Do you by any chance have _space_s in your dir names (more precisely in last one)? (if yes, you have to `cd "%lastoccur%"`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the line `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

[setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) creates a local session when it runs. You can think of this as a child cmd.exe process being spawned (it's not, but it acts like one). Everything you do after that line but before a corresponding `endlocal` (if any) is done in its own compartmentalized environment.

You are changing the directory in the newly-created local environment, but the global environment is not being changed.

You were close with your second attempt, but you cannot use variables that you create inside of code blocks without delayed expansion. You *can*, however, use the `for` loop variables to do things.

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%G in ('p4 client -o 2850NewDev ^| findstr /c:"Root:"') do (
    cd /d %%G
    echo %%G
)
```